# Conditional Expectaction 3 variables

Tags: correlation, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, conditional-expectation

Suppose $X,Y$ and $Z$ are multivariate normal with means and full covariance matrix. The conditional expectation $E(X | Y)$ is well know. What is the conditional expectation of $E(X | Y,Z)$ if $Y$ and $Z$ (and $X$) are correlated? Standard textbooks only seem to cover the case when $Y$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ are jointly Gaussian,

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{x} \\ \mathbf{y}\end{pmatrix}
\sim 
\mathcal{N}\left(
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{a} \\ \mathbf{b} \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{C} \\ \mathbf{C}^\top & \mathbf{B} \end{pmatrix}
 \right),
\end{align}

then (Rasmussen & Williams, 2006, Chapter A.2)

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{CB}^{-1}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{b}), \mathbf{A} - \mathbf{CB}^{-1}\mathbf{C}^\top \right).
\end{align}

In your case,

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x} &= x, \\
\mathbf{y} &= \begin{pmatrix} y \\ z \end{pmatrix}, \\
\mathbf{a} &= \mu_x, \\
\mathbf{b} &= \begin{pmatrix} \mu_y \\ \mu_z\end{pmatrix}, \\
\mathbf{A} &= \sigma_{xx}^2, \\
\mathbf{B} &= \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{yy}^2 & \sigma_{yz}^2 \\ \sigma_{zy}^2 & \sigma_{zz}^2 \end{pmatrix},\\
\mathbf{C} &= \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{xy}^2 & \sigma_{xz}^2 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align}

where $\sigma_{xz}^2$ is the covariance between $x$ and $z$. Hence,

$$E[x \mid y, z] = \mu_x + \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{xy}^2 & \sigma_{xz}^2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{yy}^2 & \sigma_{yz}^2 \\ \sigma_{zy}^2 & \sigma_{zz}^2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} y - \mu_y \\ z - \mu_z \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{b})^\top$ ?

Comment: It should have been $\mathbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} y & z \end{pmatrix}^\top$. I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Great, many thanks for this. Any chance you have reference with the (full) derivation of this result? I guess one could just use the derivation of $E(x | y)$ and as you did above replace y with a vector y = [y  z]'

Comment: More references: http://www3.nd.edu/~sauer/60563/Xtras/congaus.pdf http://gbhqed.wordpress.com/2010/02/21/conditional-and-marginal-distributions-of-a-multivariate-gaussian/